# Optionally build multiple jobs in a row

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

We currently have created several jobs for our components. These components all depend on each other like the following:
`A -> B -> C`

Currently it is possible to run these jobs separately independent from each other. If someone is running `C` the build uses `A` and `B` artifacts from a previous build.

Now it should be possible to *optionally* build these jobs in a row. My first thought was some kind of a `BuildAll`-job which starts the other jobs in the right order, but it does not seem to be possible to start other jobs in a buildstep.

Solving this by using the `Build other projects`-option is not a solution, because this would *always* trigger the other builds if someone e.g. starts `A`.

So anyone got an idea on how to solve this? Is something like this possible? Perhaps I missed an option/plugin to use other jobs as buildsteps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using the Parameterized Trigger plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

It allows you to trigger another job as a build step, with parameters if you need them.  This would allow you to create BuildAll job that calls A, then B, then C in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

This can help you with the "Build-All" step if you want to go down that path.

However, one part that I do not understand is that,

if `A -> B -> C`,

how are any optional? If you can clarify, might be able to help you better.

Comment: If someone just wants to start the A job, he does not need to run B and C automatically. The interface of A is changing very rarely, so B and C will still be compatible. I'll have a look at the plugin, thanks in advance.

Comment: That plugin should help you then. You can run A, B, and C independent of each other. However, if you want to run all in order, you create a "BuildAll" job that uses this plugin.